# Add multiple bookmarks and tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to add multiple tables and text to a document based on the contents of a multi column listbox.

I am able to add a table and all the other bookmarks, but for some reason when it adds the second table it overwrites the first table and so on.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me where I am going wrong with this and help me put it right.

```
Private Sub Glossaries()

Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("NewRecommendationText").Range
r.Text = "text here"
With r
.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
.InsertParagraphAfter
.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
End With

'for each item in the listbox
If lbGlossaries.ListCount > 0 Then

For k = 0 To lbGlossaries.ListCount - 1

Dim tblGloss As Table

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add ("table_" & k)
Dim bm As Range
Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("table_" & k).Range
Set tblGloss = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(bm, lbGlossaries.ListCount + 1, 5)
        'Now populate the header row
        With tblGloss
            For x = 0 To 4
                .Cell(1, x + 1).Range.Select
                If x = 0 Then
                Set_Table_Headers "Customer Name"
                ElseIf x = 1 Then
                    Set_Table_Headers "Product"
                ElseIf x = 2 Then
                    Set_Table_Headers "Fund"
                ElseIf x = 3 Then
                    Set_Table_Headers "Risk Profile"
                ElseIf x = 4 Then
                    Set_Table_Headers "Lump Sum Amount"
                End If
            Next
        End With

        With tblGloss


            .Cell(i + 2, 0).Range.Select
            Set_Table_Rows


            Selection.TypeText Text:=lbGlossaries.Column(0, k)   ' customer
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.TypeText Text:=lbGlossaries.Column(1, k) ' selected product
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.TypeText Text:=lbGlossaries.Column(2, k) ' selected fund
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.TypeText Text:=lbGlossaries.Column(3, k) ' risk profile
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            Selection.TypeText Text:=lbGlossaries.Column(4, k) ' amount
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
            'Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdExtend
            'Selection.Cells.Merge
            'Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            'Selection.TypeText Text:=lbGlossaries.Column(5, i) ' reason


        tblGloss.Select
        tblGloss.Columns.AutoFit
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
        End With

        With bm
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End With

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add ("reason_" & k)
        Dim reason As Range
        Set reason = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("reason_" & k).Range
        reason.Text = lbGlossaries.Column(5, k) ' reason



        ''add the glossary text under here
        activeBookmark = activeBookmark & "_glossary" & k
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add (activeBookmark)

        Dim glossary As Range
        Set glossary = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(activeBookmark).Range
        glossary.Text = lbGlossaries.Column(6, i) & Chr(13) & Chr(13)

        ''add the tax glossary text under here
        activeBookmark = activeBookmark & "_Tax_glossary" & k
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add (activeBookmark)

        Dim TaxGlossary As Range
        Set TaxGlossary = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(activeBookmark).Range
        TaxGlossary.Text = lbGlossaries.Column(7, i) & Chr(13) & Chr(13)

        ''add the encashment glossary text under here
        activeBookmark = activeBookmark & "_Encashment_glossary" & k
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add (activeBookmark)
        Dim encashment As Range
        Set encashment = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(activeBookmark).Range
        encashment.Text = lbGlossaries.Column(8, i) & Chr(13) & Chr(13)

        ''add the encashment designation text under here
        activeBookmark = activeBookmark & "_designation" & k
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add (activeBookmark)

        Dim designation As Range
        Set designation = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(activeBookmark).Range
        If lbCgt.Column(9, k) <> "" Then
            designation.Text = lbGlossaries.Column(10, i)
        Else
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(activeBookmark).Delete
        End If




Next
End If
```

Comment: Try specifying the range when inserting bookmarks. The way it is now, all the bookmarks are inserted at the current selection (right after the first table) and the text is inserted after the bookmarks. That means the last text that was inserted appears at the top. The next table is inserted right after the first one and merges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this out now

i wasnt selecting the range  this is how i resolved it

```
encashment.Select
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeParagraph
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add
....
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is that you don't specify *where* in the document the new bookmark(s) should be added. `Bookmarks.Add` has a second, optional parameter `Range` that lets you specify where to create the Bookmark. If you don't provide that information, Word will put it where it wants - you have no control.

Assuming it should follow at the end of `r` then something like this:

```
Dim bm As Range
Set bm = r.Duplicate
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add ("table_" & k, bm)
' Do things...
Dim reason As Range
Set reason = bm.Duplicate
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add ("reason_" & k, reason)
```

Comment: thanks for the comments, and the solution i will test this but solved it before the response.

Comment: @SimonPrice Glad you found something that works, but you should avoid using the Selection object whenever possible. It's better to work with Range objects: more predictable (user clicking on the document while code is executing can't change the position); code is more readable; you can work with more than one Range, but only one Selection.